# How can I make Vue discover components loaded into the instance during runtime using AJAX

Tags: ajax, vue.js

I am trying to implement Vue in my website boilerplate, that runs on Wordpress or Craft using twig templates. The boilerplate uses [Swup](https://swup.js.org/) to make transitions between pages, while only loading the changed content. Currently I am making all my reactive elements as separate Vue components. Some of them gets loaded into the app through 'swupped' content.

So in the setup below I run a Vue app in #app that compiles during runtime which has a `header` and a `footer` component. Swup handles the content inside #swup, so this changes when a user clicks a link. So at times it may have plain text content, but other times it has a `slider` component.

```
<div id="#app">
  <header><header>
    <div id="#swup">
      ?<slider>?
    </div>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Swup emits events on which I wanted to hook the #app in. So after a transition I tried to destroy the instance and then reinit my app:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

However this doesn't work: it doesn't load the `slider` component and the `header` and `footer` component stopped working. I feel like I'm forcing Vue into something that it isn't build for.

Comment: **Swup** is not a recommended library to use with **VueJS** - you can find a filed issue about that on the link in my answer. Try to use **VueJS**'s own transition functions.

Answer (score 2):

It is suggested that you use **VueJS** own, built-in animation-transition for this purpose.

More:

- **VueJS** with **Swup**: https://github.com/swup/swup/issues/10
- **VueJS** docs on animation/transition: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html
- Animation with **VueJS**: https://css-tricks.com/native-like-animations-for-page-transitions-on-the-web/

But, if you'd really like to get this working, you might do something like this:

```js
const TextComponent = {
  template: '<div>This is a text component</div>'
}

const OtherTextComponent = {
  template: '<div>This is the other text component</div>'
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    TextComponent,
    OtherTextComponent
  },
  data: {
    comp: 'TextComponent'
  },
  methods: {
    changeComponent(comp) {
      if (comp === 'TextComponent') {
        this.comp = 'OtherTextComponent'
      } else {
        this.comp = 'TextComponent'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="changeComponent(comp)">CHANGE COMPONENT</button>
  <hr>
  <component v-bind:is="comp"></component>
</div>
```

The "trick" here is that the general `component` tag is used with `v-bind:is`. But you have to register the components that you plan on using. So, when **Swup** changes the content, only the component name should change. (Important note: I haven't tested **Swup** before, so this solution might not work.)

- **VueJS** component registration: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html

This is NOT runtime component compilation - that's another topic.

Comment: This however switches components in and out. But I want to switch out a complete <main> content which might have multiple components. Like it switches between the home page and about page.

Comment: Then you need a router plugin, e.g. **vue-router**. That also supports (page) transitions.

Answer (score 0):

This github issue helped me to get it working:
https://github.com/swup/swup/issues/208

There is a small difference in my original setup (which breaks) and the setup provided by Iklion. The Vue instance used the same container as the Swup instance, instead of encapsulating Swup within a Vue container. Placing Swup outside of the Vue instance works as well, like so:

```
<#swup>
  <#app>
    <header>
    <main>
    <footer>
  </#app>
</#swup>
```

I was afraid swup would change the complete page, but actually is still only switching out the `main` part, since the `header` and `footer` dont change.